# Django signal receiver accepts self argument

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I am making a game. Every time a certain action occurs it sends a signal. The signal is used by many different objects. For example, player model instances will regenerate a little bit of health, lanterns will  decrease the oil they have left. I want instances of these model to react and modify their data when the signal is emitted. However, I don't know how to refer to the instance itself in the receiver function, since I can't put "self" in the list of arguments the function uses.

```
class Lantern(models.Model):
    oil_left= models.IntegerField(default=4)

    @receiver(mySignal)
    def burn(sender, **kwargs):
        self.oil_left  -= 1 #<- self is not defined obviously
        self.save() #<- self is not defined obviously
```

Why receiver as an instance method? Because the list of instances reacting to the signal is unknown when signal is sent. The signal is merely a ping notifying interested objects (i.e. with a receiver method) that an event occurred so they can trigger their own specific behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want the signal to be an instance method? There doesn't seem to be any reason for it. You just need to ensure that when you write the signal function itself, it passes the relevant instance - eg as an `instance` kwarg - exactly as the built-in `pre-save` and `post-save` signals do.

**Added after edit to question** But that is exactly how signals are supposed to work. There's a single signal function, which sends the signal along with any association information, and any number of receivers that listen to the signal. But the receivers themselves aren't associated with particular instances - they can't be, an instance only exists when you actually instantiate it(!) and otherwise it's just a row in a database.

Perhaps your receiver function could query for the relevant objects itself, and update them there - or even better, do an `update` query to change them in-place.

Comment: (I added more info in my question) In the case of pre-save and post-save, they are emitted by an instance (my signal is sent from a non-model classes) but in the end it doesn't make a difference what sends the signal in my case, it's what receives it that is important hence the need for instance receiver methods. To reuse my example, only wounded players would regenerate their health, checking a player’s health state would be done in the player's instance receiver method. But maybe I'm completely wrong and this design is not possible the way signals are working.

Comment: Ok, what if I wanted to run the receiver method on a normal python object, not on a model instance, and have it refer to it"self" in the receiver method? Would is be possible in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Signal is not about your model object class changes, it is about some stuff to be done every time after/before you write to database in table assosiated with model

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=YourModel)
def your_action_call(sender, instance, **kwargs):
   pass
   #some logic
```